# Concatenate string with html in liquid Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

```
{% assign price = product.price | money %}
{% capture dot_separator %} <span class='Button__SeparatorDot'></span> {% endcapture %}
{% capture addToCartText %} ADD TO CART {{ dot_separator }} {{ product_price_formatted }} {% endcapture %}
 
{{ addToCartText }}
```

My goal is to show the "addToCartText" text this way

**Goal:** ADD TO CART . 287$

Where the dot is created using css

Right now it's showing like this

**Current output:** ADD TO CART < span class='Button__SeparatorDot'></ span> 287$

How would I tell liquid to read the html as it is?

Comment: It working fine on my side, did you check it again

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `strip_html` filter https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/strip_html/

like so:

```
{% capture dot_separator %} < span class='Button__SeparatorDot'></ span> {% endcapture %}
{% capture addToCartText %} ADD TO CART {{ dot_separator | strip_html }} {{ product_price_formatted }} {% endcapture %}
 
{{ addToCartText }}
```